# Writing a list into a txt file

Tags: r

I want to write a list of paragraphs into a txt file to view after manipulating them, the list is called `psw_list` and you can reference the first paragraph by using `psw_list$p1`. `psw_list$p1` looks like:

```
> psw_list$p1
[1] "For more than five years, William Sencion did the same task over and over. He signed onto the New York City’s housing lottery site and applied for one of the city’s highly coveted, below-market apartments. Each time, he got the same response: silence."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write(...) function is what you are looking for. If you want to write all of the paragraphs to one file you need to use the unlist(...) function, as seen below.

These functions will dump the resulting .txts into your working directory.

```
psw_list <- c()
psw_list$p1 <- "For more than five years, William Sencion did the same task over and over. He signed onto the New York City’s housing lottery site and applied for one of the city’s highly coveted, below-market apartments. Each time, he got the same response: silence."
psw_list$p2 <- "Something something dark side. Luke I am your father."

write(psw_list$p1, "first_paragraph.txt")
write(unlist(psw_list), "all_pragraphs.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So I'm relatively new to R, does the unlist function literally just make a list not a list?

Comment: In this case you can think of the unlist function as pasting those two strings together as one long string. There is (technically) more to it than that but you can think of it this way. If my answer helped you then please click the check mark and accept it!